# Looking for a way to have awk iteratively loop through a file (to create PERCENTRANK function in bash)

Tags: bash, unix, awk, gawk

My file **data.txt** contains the following record structure with millions of rows:

```
13
12
11
8
4
3
2
1
1
1
```

For every value of this column, I need to calculate its PERCENTRANK (which is the rank of a value in a data set as a percentage of the data set).

The formula to calculate the PERCENTRANK of any value X in the data set is

```
= number of values less than X / (Number of values less than X + Number of Values greater than X)
```

So, for every value X in the data set, the program has to loop through all the records to find the number of values less than and greater than X in the same data set.

How can this be implemented using 'awk' to repeatedly loop through the file to calculate PERCENTRANK for all values of X?

Expected output:

```
X    PERCENTRANK
13   1.0000
12   0.8888
11   0.7777
8    0.6666
4    0.5555
3    0.4444
2    0.3333
1    0.0000
1    0.0000
1    0.0000
```

PERCENTRANK of 2 is 0.333 because three values in the set are less than 2, and six are greater than 2. PERCENTRANK OF 2 = 3 / (3 + 6) = 3/9 = 0.3333.

Similarly, PERCENTRANK of 4 is 0.5555 because five values are less than 4, and four are greater. PERCENTRANK OF 4 = 5 / (5 + 4) = 5 / 9 = 0.5555.

I am avoiding a nested 'while..do' loop because it is terribly slow when looping through a file containing millions of records.

I have been pleased with the amazing speed of awk in many other iterative computing scenarios, for example: calculating averages, standard deviations, group by sum, etc. and so, I would ideally like to use 'awk' to solve this use case as well.

Comment: Have you considered sorting the list?

Comment: @Thor: Yes, I have sorted the list. However, as I understand, in 'awk' pre-sorting is not a requirement.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, the input set is representative sample from a dataset containing several million rows. So, there are records before and after the sample in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following simpler `sort` and `awk` approach may also help you in same(though I haven't tested it on millions of lines, since I didn't have it).

***Solution 1st:*** This will not show duplicate item's rank in output eg--> digit 1 in your example.

```
sort -nr Input_file | awk '
function sum(array){
  tot="";
  for(i in array){
    tot+=array[i]};
  return tot}
{
  a[FNR]=$0;
  b[$0]++
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=FNR;j++){
    if(b[a[j]]){
      val=b[a[j]];
      delete b[a[j]];
      printf("%d %0.4f\n",a[j],sum(b)/(sum(d)+sum(b)));
      d[a[j]]=val;}
}}
'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
13 1.0000
12 0.8889
11 0.7778
8 0.6667
4 0.5556
3 0.4444
2 0.3333
1 0.0000
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding solution(a minor different from 1st one) which will provide even duplicate item's RANK too in output as follows.

```
sort -nr Input_file | awk '
function sum(array){
  tot="";
  for(i in array){
    tot+=array[i]};
  return tot}
{
  a[FNR]=$0;
  b[$0]++
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=FNR;j++){
    if(b[a[j]]){
      val=val1=b[a[j]];
      delete b[a[j]];
      while(val1>0){
      printf("%d %0.4f\n",a[j],sum(b)/(sum(d)+sum(b)));
      val1--}
      d[a[j]]=val;}
}}
'
13 1.0000
12 0.8889
11 0.7778
8 0.6667
4 0.5556
3 0.4444
2 0.3333
1 0.0000
1 0.0000
1 0.0000
```

Comment: thanks a lot for providing both the options! Both these code work perfectly and accurately for larger datasets.

It is very useful to have your second option, especially for very large datasets (to save on avoidable CPU time when such datasets contain a several duplicate numbers).

Comment: @CF-RV, how the performance is coming on this? Kindly do let me know your results on same.

Answer (score 5):

GNU awk

```
gawk '
    {count[$1]++}
    END {
        print "X\tPERCENTRANK"
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_desc"
        gt = 0
        total = NR
        for (x in count) {
            lt = total - count[x] - gt
            pr = lt/(gt+lt)
            for (i=1; i<=count[x]; i++)
                printf "%d\t%.4f\n", x, pr
            gt += count[x]
        }
    }
' data.txt
```

```
X       PERCENTRANK
13      1.0000
12      0.8889
11      0.7778
8       0.6667
4       0.5556
3       0.4444
2       0.3333
1       0.0000
1       0.0000
1       0.0000
```

This should be pretty efficient even with large datasets: there are no nested loops.

This relies on GNU awk to set the order for traversing the `count` array: ordered by array index, descending numerically. Since we enforce the order, we can simply keep a count of how many records are greater then an the one we're currently looking at.

Comment: Well, there is ONE nested loop (`for (x in count) { ... for (i=1; i<=count[x]; i++)`. I do agree it should be efficient though. +1.

Comment: @glenn.. Honestly saying from logic vice seems our approach is same, though you have done the GOOD JOB within a single awk itself, I just googled and read about `ind_num_desc` my`awk` version is not having it but good to read about it, ++ for nice solution sir.

Comment: @glenn - thanks for that elegant code.
I am using the following bash version - GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on Amazon EC2 instance.

I get the following incorrect result with your code:

    X       PERCENTRANK
    4       1.0000
    8       0.8889
    11      0.7778
    12      0.6667
    13      0.5556
    1       0.2857
    1       0.2857
    1       0.2857
    2       0.1111
    3       0.0000

Comment: The bash version is irrelevant. Do you have `gawk` or plain awk?